# bash script not executing mysql command with values passed as variables

Tags: php, mysql, bash, macos, python-3.x

I am modifying a set of bash scripts that process video files and reports the processing steps to a mysql database (here is the [original code](https://github.com/mediamicroservices/mm/blob/master/mmfunctions) in question).

The function that does the database reporting is called from the main processing script and looks like this in the original:

```
_report_to_db(){
if [ "${REPORT_TO_DB}" = "Y" ] ; then
    echo "INSERT IGNORE INTO tableA (objectIdentifierValue,object_LastTouched) VALUES ('${MEDIA_ID}',NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE object_LastTouched = NOW()" | mysql --login-path="${LOGIN_PROFILE}"  "${DB_NAME}" 2> /dev/null
    _db_error_check
fi
}
```

Since the scripts are meant to be run directly from the command line, when you run them that way it works fine. But I'm running them via php from a web interface and there's some shenanigans going on with the quoting/escaping of whitespace and/or variables.

For instance, the script breaks on the whitespace after `...| mysql` and it thinks I'm trying to run mysql as root without a password and totally ignores the `--login-path` and the other stuff I'm piping to it.

When I call `mysql` from a variable like so:

```
_report_to_db(){
    if [ "${REPORT_TO_DB}" = "Y" ] ; then

        SQL_ARRAY=(INSERT IGNORE INTO tableA (columnA,lastTouched) VALUES ("${SOME_PASSED_VALUE}",NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE object_LastTouched = NOW();)
        MYSQL_COMMAND_ARRAY=(mysql --login-path="${LOGIN_PROFILE}" -e "${SQL_ARRAY[@]}" "${DB_NAME}")

        echo "$(${MYSQL_COMMAND_ARRAY[@]})"

        _db_error_check

    fi
}
```

... I am able to log into mysql correctly but the SQL query is ignored (when it `echo`s the result you get the standard MySQL `--help` output.

So far I have tried all kinds of variations on quoting, escaping, referencing the query as a separate string variable, as an array (as you see here).

What is also not helpful is that the original `_db_error_check()` function only checks the value of the pipe exit status. So if the pipe is ok, but there's a problem further down the path, it fails silently.

```
_db_error_check(){
    if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
    # reports an error if the pipe exit value ≠ 0
    else 
    # everything is ok! even if there was a mysql error
    fi
}
```

This is not a file or database permissions issue (already triple checked that). Are there quotes or some other stupid thing that I am missing?? Thanks! Oh, I am running OSX El Capitan.

**UPDATE**

Lol, I was going to post the PHP that calls the script and then I remembered that the PHP is actually calling a Pyhton script that does some other processing too, and *that* is what calls the bash script. Here it all is:

**PHP**

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/path/to/ingest.py " . $user . " 2>&1");

while (@ ob_end_flush());
$proc = popen($command, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
```

**PYTHON**

```
for item in os.listdir(ingestDir):
    if not item.startswith("."):
        filePath = os.path.abspath(ingestDir+"/"+item)
        fileNameForMediaID = os.path.splitext(item)[0]
        try:
            ingest = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/ingestfile','-e','-u',user,'-I',filePath,'-m',fileNameForMediaID])
            ingest.wait()
            os.remove(filePath)
        except IOError as err:
            print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I think this might *actually* be a weird quirk of my installation (go figure). Using `mysql --login-path=myDbUser [etc...]` from a shell on my host machine I keep getting the error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ADMIN'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` where the client user is `ADMIN` and I am trying to login as `myDbUser`.

I actually [uninstalled and reinstalled mysql](https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks) (via Homebrew) and still have the same results. Using a different machine (running Sierra, but the same mysql version) I can run the above shell command successfully and log into mysql as the target user.

Also on the host machine, I can `sudo -u _www zsh` and run the command as the Apache user (which is the user running the whole show) without a problem. SO WHY IS IT NOT RUNNING CORRECTLY EITHER IN THE SCRIPT OR EVEN RUN FROM SHELL AS MY MAIN CLIENT USER???

Any ideas? `$PATH` is identical in all cases mentioned above. Same `~/.mylogin.cnf` setups. Is there anything else stupid obvious I missed?

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you are using to call this script ?  (Just that 1 line that does the call should be enough. )

Comment: @gregn3 thanks! Ha, the code that calls it is more convoluted than I remembered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use indirect expansion here:

```
  echo "$(${MYSQL_COMMAND_ARRAY[@]})"
```

the [man says:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and
>   parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable
>   indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>   of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then
>   expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution,
>   rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect
>   expansion. If parameter is a nameref, this expands to the name of the
>   variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the complete
>   indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the expansions of
>   ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. The exclamation point
>   must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce
>   indirection.
>
> ```
>    ${!name[@]}
>    ${!name[*]}
> ```
>
> If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices
>   (keys) assigned in name. If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name
>   is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears
>   within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.

PS: If I may put forward a piece of my personal opinion, having a chain of php -> python -> bash is the worst coding style one can ever met, you may want to rewrite it into single langue so it will be easier to track down further issues at least.

Comment: thanks @dmytro ! I don't think that's quite what I was looking for. Indirect expansion expanded the array of command variables to the index of each variable. I tried to get it to expand to the variables themselves , but no luck. I tried many variations on quoting and didn't get anywhere.

Is there a specific format you had in mind? Any other ideas would be great!

Also, I agree--if I had time I would want this to be in a single language, but there are 10's of thousands of lines of code in the suite of Bash scripts that I am using.